# kubectl rolling-update rc correspond to api?

Tags: kubernetes

> kubectl rolling-update foo new_image.
>   What interface API for rolling-update? Give an example for update new image?
>   thanks!

Comment: Give an example for update new image by api?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API method for rolling-update, the CLI makes calls to the pod and replicationcontroller APIs behind the scenes to achieve a rolling update

Comment: Expected to provide rolling-update for api method in future.  CLI makes calls to pod and rc apis, Give calls api  detailed list?

Answer (score 0):

If you run "kubectl help rollingupdate" you will get the answer to your question. (And new_image is a docker image.)

Additional documentation:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/docs/user-guide/update-demo

Comment: I want to update image by request api, Give an example for update new image by api request?

Comment: I find all api method(by swagger ui), but don't find rolling update method?

Comment: Try running the demo linked by DavidO, but change the actual `rolling-update` command to use the `--v=8`    flag, like this: `kubectl rolling-update update-demo-nautilus --update-period=2s -f docs/user-guide/update-demo/kitten-rc.yaml --v=8`. You will see all of the API calls needed and their request/response. As csanchez mentions below, there is not a single call; this example appears to make 39 API calls to finish the update.

Answer (score 0):

If you check fabric8 rolling-update implementation (API mentioned below), they are creating a new replica set with a same deployed replica set spec and they increase the count in new replica set and wait for it to complete and then they decrease count from old deployed replica-set, thus maintaining availability.

```html
    private static void updateRc(KubernetesClient client){
        System.out.println("updating rollinh");
       // client.replicationControllers().inNamespace("default").withName("my-nginx").rolling().updateImage("nginx:latest");
        client.extensions().replicaSets().inNamespace("default").withName("fgrg-73-nginxcontainer1-74-97775d4d8").rolling().updateImage("nginx:latest");
        System.out.println("done");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do rolling update via api is to first check if `deployment.spec.updateStrategy` is `RollingUpdate` and if not then update it after this just edit the deployment with the new image tag.